# Can my Canon EOS1300D be set to turn off the LCD display when I use the viewfinder?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, rear-lcd

I am new to Photography using DSLR. I recently bought a Canon EOS 1300D and I was checking it. I have seen some cameras that their LCD display goes off once you bring your eye close to the viewfinder. But in my Canon EOS 1300D it's not happening. Is it because this model doesn't have a sensor for that, or do I have to set something? I don't want the LCD display to stay on all the time, that's why am asking.

Answer (score 2):

No, your camera does not have a sensor that detects if your eye is near the viewfinder. You can manually turn off the LCD by pressing the <kbd>DISP.</kbd> button. Also, you can set the LCD to turn off when you half-press the shutter button. On page 197 of the [user manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300022698/01/eos-rebelt6-1300d-im-en.pdf), the options under <kbd>MENU</kbd>, **[LCD off/on btn]** setting are:

> - **[Shutter btn.]:** When you press the shutter button halfway, the display will turn off. When you let go of the shutter button, the display will turn on.
> - **[Shutter/DISP]:** When you press the shutter button halfway, the display will turn off. The display will remain off even after you let go of the shutter button. To turn on the display, press the <DISP.> button.
> - **[Remains on]:** Display remains on even when you press the shutter button halfway. To turn off the display, press the <DISP.> button.